# JPA EclipseLink - The expression is not a valid conditional expression

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, windows-7, eclipselink, language-packs

Although there is nothing wrong with this query, eclipselink throws this exception.

> [34, 130] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.

I am trying to run Spring boot with Jpa/eclipselink in windows 7.

**The problem occurs when I change system language to Turkish.**

Why eclipselink doesnt work on OS that uses Turkish lang? When I change system language to English, it works fine.

Please somebody help me out.

Query:

```
return em.createQuery("select c from Orderdetail c where c.status=1 and c.triggertime > 0 and c.printstatus = 0 and c.idorder.idorderstatus.id in (1, 4)").setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE).getResultList();
```

This is another query parsing error. Full log

```
    Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select c from Orderdetail c where c.status=1 and c.triggertime > 0 and c.printstatus = 0 and c.idorder.idorderstatus.id in (1, 4)]. 
[34, 131] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:367) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:127) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at tr.com.abeja.acservice.repository.DictionariesRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c377301.findTriggeredOrderDetails(<generated>) ~[classes!/:3.2.1]
    at tr.com.abeja.acservice.service.DictsController.findAndPrintTriggeredOrderDetails(DictsController.java:887) ~[classes!/:3.2.1]
    at tr.com.abeja.acservice.controller.DictsResource.updateTimerProductsPrice(DictsResource.java:48) ~[classes!/:3.2.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select c from Orderdetail c where c.status=1 and c.triggertime > 0 and c.printstatus = 0 and c.idorder.idorderstatus.id in (1, 4)]. 
[34, 131] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1746) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at tr.com.abeja.acservice.repository.DictionariesRepository.findTriggeredOrderDetails(DictionariesRepository.java:857) ~[classes!/:3.2.1]
    at tr.com.abeja.acservice.repository.DictionariesRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a490717.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select c from Orderdetail c where c.status=1 and c.triggertime > 0 and c.printstatus = 0 and c.idorder.idorderstatus.id in (1, 4)]. 
[34, 131] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:157) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:336) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:280) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:165) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:118) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:104) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:88) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1744) ~[eclipselink-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could you show us the entire lig, I mean all the exception message.

Comment: Updated the answer. There is not anything related to system language pack in the error log. It just fails to parse jpql

Comment: You are using HQL or JPQL?

Comment: I am using JPQL

Comment: try to change c.status=1 to c.status = 1 in the query, just add two spaces.

Comment: actually when i removed this line `and c.idorder.idorderstatus.id in (1, 4)`  it worked. Apparently,  `c.idorder.idorderstatus.id` causing problem. But i should not remove that part from query, i am looking for what is causing this parse error.

Comment: So I think you must use join aspect, so I think you must look for JPQL and Criteria API to use join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

After spending hours of debugging, I found the reason of this exception.

LSS: Exception was occurring in `HermesParser` which is query parser in eclipselink. Starting from there, i found a code that converts `in`, `and`, `or`, `like` etc parts of jpql to uppercase.

Part of my query(failing to parse).

```
and c.idorder.idorderstatus.id in (1, 4)
```

Here `and` and `in` gets converted to uppercase `AND` and `IN`. The problem is, in turkish, uppercase of `i` letter is `İ`(dotted I), so upprecase of `in` is `İN` which is incorrect expression. When Operation system language is in Turkish, uppercase method converts `i` to `İ`. That was the problem.

I changed all lowercase letters in jpql to uppercase beforehand, and solved the problem.

Hope it helps someone else ever encountered with this problem

Comment: Oh god. This issue showed up on a software I'm maintaining. Exactly with turkish. Is there any other language I must be afraid of? Searching for IN and LIKE is already an issue, but if it would hapen with 'e', or 'o' would imply I would need to fix a lot of queries.

Comment: no problems with o and e. only expressions with " i ". convert to uppercase I